# pandas average multi level columns

Tags: pandas, multi-level

I have a pandas table with multi level columns:

[image]
How can I average the columns with same level 0 name ?

so basically all columns(could be more than 2) under g1 will be averaged to one column for each row 
and then all columns under g2 will be averaged to one column for each row 
and so on...

I can do this with a for loop but is there a better way to get this output df:

| exp | g1 | g2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| e1 | 0.7... derived as avg(1, 0.44..) | 0.54.. |
| e2 | 0.7.. | -0.05.. |

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I managed it with a group by:

`df.groupby(by=df.columns.get_level_values(0), axis=1).mean()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do `groupby` on columns with `axis=1` and specify the `level`

```
out = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).mean()
```

```
print(df)

  g1         g2
  e1    e2   e1    e2
0  1  0.44  0.9  0.14

print(out)

     g1    g2
0  0.72  0.52
```

Comment: Thanks. Yep, came to the same solution. Thanks :)